# Android - Struggiling to layout my application when virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm struggling in a very annoying problem for my `Android` App.
I created an `Activity` for registering to my App.

**This is the `Activity` xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/appTitleBar"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/activityTitleBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appTitleBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/signinActivityTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:text="Welcome. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activityTitleBar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:hint="password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:hint="confirm" />

    <Button
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can seeת I'm using two `Toolbars` (I've selected a `NoActionBar` theme), one for the App name and one for the `Activity` title.

Then I placed a `TextView` that contains a welcome message and an introduction of the App.

Finally, there is the sign in form, composed of two `EditText` (for password and password confirmation) and one `Button` that submit the passwords in order to be processed later.

**Here, it is how appears in the "normal state":**

[image]

**This, instead is the program when the virtual keyboard is on:**

[image]

**And here are the problems:**

First problem is, that the toolbars disappear. And I don't want it.
Second problem is, that I want that all the form (the two edit-text and the `Button`) must be above the keyboard. Instead, only the first edit-text is above.
In addition the welcome `TextView` has to desappear.

**In practice I would like that my App be like this when the virtual keyboard is up:**

[image]

I tried to play with

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

Comment: Wrap your form in a `<ScrollView>` and keep the `adjustResize`, I think you'll obtain what you're looking for. Otherwise Android needs to accommodate the lack of space by moving the entire page (since it's not scrollable). But you'll still get the keyboard just under the focused EditText. What I've seen some apps do (see Chase bank app) is they'll have the form in a floating dialogue and keep the content minimal so you can guarantee the button and edit texts will be above the KB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is using `ScrollView`:

[image]

**Define the `ScroolView` in your `Layout` like below (or just copy paste the code):**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.igor.test.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/appTitleBar"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/activityTitleBar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appTitleBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="signinActivityTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroolView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/activityTitleBar">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
    <TextView
        android:text="Welcome. bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:hint="password" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText3"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:hint="confirm" />

    <Button
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your `Activity` set the referance of the `ScrollView` and the main `RelativeLayout`
Also set `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` on your main `RelativeLayout` and implements the `onGlobalLayout()` method.

**Take a look at the example below:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    private ScrollView scrollView;
    private RelativeLayout activity_main_RL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroolView);
        activity_main_RL = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        activity_main_RL.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int heightDiff = activity_main_RL.getRootView().getHeight() - activity_main_RL.getHeight();

                if (heightDiff > 100) {
                    scrollView.scrollBy(0, scrollView.getBottom());
                }
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```